# Change port and host using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, subdomain, portforwarding

I am trying to use `mod_rewrite` to basically port forward a port on a subdomain to another port on another IP.

Like this:

```
sub.website.com:2000 --> 123.45.67.891:3000
```

How could this be accomplished using a `.htaccess` file with  `mod_rewrite`?

I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.website.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^2000$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://123.45.67.891:3000/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: The rule looks pretty simple. What does "to no avail" mean? Have you any errors? Does the page from `sub.website.com` show up? Something else?

Comment: It simply does not forward the port correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing with your rules, I found out that `HTTP_HOST` includes the port number. So the rules should look like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.website.com:2000$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^2000$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://123.45.67.891:3000/$1 [L,R=302]
```

If you want to test against server name alone, you could use `%{SERVER_NAME}` as @faa suggested in the comments

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^sub.website.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and testing against the server name alone works correctly however attempting to specify a port does not. I''m trying it here with port 2000 but Safari just tells me that the server where the page is located is not responding. This is my `.htaccess` file: http://pastebin.com/aqjwgZjb

Comment: @Joshua Then the virtual host isn't setup to listen on port 2000. You must say `Listen 2000` and `<VirtualHost *:2000>...</VirtualHost>` or `<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:2000>...</VirtualHost>` in the virtual host configuration.